# error: no type named 'value_type' in 'class boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >'

Tags: c++, templates, point-cloud-library

I have some code looks like the following:

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB pcl_ColorPointType;
typedef pcl::PointXYZ pcl_PointType;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl_PointType> pcl_XYZPointCloudType;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl_ColorPointType> pcl_ColorPointCloudType;
typedef pcl_XYZPointCloudType::Ptr pcl_XYZPointCloudPtrType;
typedef pcl_ColorPointCloudType::Ptr pcl_ColorPointCloudPtrType;

void
BuildMeshFromDepthImage()
{
    pcl_XYZPointCloudConstPtrType pointCloud = BuildPurePointCloudFromDepthImage( ); // assume BuildPurePointCloudFromDepthImage function exists
    BuildMeshFromPointCloud<pcl_XYZPointCloudConstPtrType>( pointCloud );
}

template<typename T_pclPtr>
void BuildMeshFromPointCloud(const T_pclPtr &pointCloud )
{
    // some code

    // error: no type named 'value_type'
    const typename T_pclPtr::value_type::PointType& pt = pointCloud->points[i]; 

    // some code
}
```

Any idea why this does not work? P.S. This code works under VS2010 but not with GCC4.9. Could that be because of different version of PCL library?

Comment: _Could that be because of different version of PCL library?_ Maybe yes, [pcl version 1.8](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html) define `pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr` as `boost::shared_ptr< PointCloud< T > >`

Comment: @Danh, That's what I suspected as well, but I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `typename T_pclPtr::element_type::PointType& t= pointCloud->points[i]; `

Comment: if you are using C++11 or later, just `auto t = pointCloud->points[i];`

Comment: oo..that made the error disappeared!! Any good reference to help me  understand this? (element_type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pcl::PointCloud< PointT > Class Template Reference](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html)

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< PointCloud< PointT > >   Ptr
```

and [Boost.SharedPtr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm?sess=ivjlrusbytqsdq#Members)

> element_type is T when T is not an array type, and U when T is U[] or U[N].

This is what you need:

```
typename T_pclPtr::element_type::PointType& t= pointCloud->points[i];
```

For C++11 or later, you can use this:

```
auto t= pointCloud->points[i];
```